# How to handle Docker-Secrets in application.properties files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-secrets

How do you inject Docker secrets (files/data from /run/secrets) into the application.properties files? Is it safe to use environment variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, usage of environment variables for secret data for the `application.properties` isn't safe.

You have mainly two options when talking about Secrets.

1. If you are using Docker Secrets **without Docker Swarm** then you can directly load the whole `application.properties` in a secret, mount it under `/run/secrets` and refer to it as configuration file with the Spring flags.
2. If you are using Docker Secrets **with Docker Swarm** then you can just store as secret the concrete fields that you're interested in and relate to them using the Configuration Templates of Swarm.

Example:

```
echo -n "myUser" | docker secret create db_user -
echo -n "myPass" | docker secret create db_password -
echo -n "jdbc://..." | docker secret create db_url -
```

**application.properties.tmpl**

```
spring.datasource.url={{ secret "db_url" }}
spring.datasource.user={{ secret "db_user" }}
spring.datasource.password={{ secret "db_password" }}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  api:
    image: yourapp:1.0.0
  configs:
    - source: application.properties
      target: /usr/app/config/application.properties
  secrets:
    - db_url
    - db_user
    - db_password

configs:
  application.properties:
    template_driver: golang
    file: ./application.properties.tmpl
    name: myapp.application.properties

secrets:
  db_url:
    external: true
  db_user:
    external: true
  db_password:
    external: true
```

When you deploy with `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml myapp`, it will automatically populate the configuration with the contents of the secrets and it will mount it in the destination path.

Comment: Oh wow! Didn't think about docker configs! Nice approach, thank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: If this answered your question, mark it as accepted so the rest of users will find it at a glance as well. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Is it possible to use external configs with templates? @daniel-campos

Comment: I had to remove the spaces before "secret", then it was working!

Comment: I like this solution but if I understand it correctly, the `application.properties` file is available in the container in plain text so can be read by shelling into the container? Then assuming that anyone that gains access to the compose file potentially has access to the running container as well thus this is no more secure than using environment variables? Is the real benefit that secrets are transmitted securely between nodes in a swarm whereas environment variables are not?

Comment: @D-Dᴙum environment variables can be retrieved from outside of the running container, and multiple processes could dump them as part of their debug cycle in STDOUT. This is very dangerous if you're treating sensible data. I totally agree that the existence of the file itself mounted in the container isn't perfect, but is as perfect as it gets and there are ways to prevent access from the shell to that concrete file. There are other options, as using Vault with K8s Auth configured for the Service Account which is using your service, if we were in a K8s context, but that doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 11):

The best way to use docker secrets in application.properties seems to be using configuration trees.

If your docker secrets get mounted to /run/secrets (which is the default) then you just need to put `spring.config.import=optional:configtree:/run/secrets/` at the top of application.properties. Then you can use for example the docker secret `db_password` as `${db_password}`.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.configtree

Comment: I tested this awesomely simple solution on both Windows and a CentOS machine, and it worked !

Comment: Thanks! this is also working like a charm for secrets of docker-compose which is explained here https://serverfault.com/a/936262

Answer (score 0):

If you subscribe to the *Twelve-Factor App* philosophy on [configuration](https://12factor.net/), environment variables are the appropriate place to store secrets for your app.

With Spring Boot, specifically, it is possible to set them as env vars in your container following an `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` naming convention which maps to the keys in your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file. For example, if you wanted to set a database password as if it were defined as `database.password=i-am-the-password` in your `application.properties` file but omit this from version control, you could do:

```sh
$ export DATABASE_PASSWORD=i-am-the-password
```

(Or another method of injecting the env var into your container runtime.)

The database password would then be accessible in Java code as:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class Example {

  private final String databasePassword;

  public Example(
      @Value("${database.password}") String databasePassword) {

    this.databasePassword = databasePassword;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do think environment variables are unsafe to use here (https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#:~:text=docker%20secrets%20do%20not%20set%20environment%20variables%20directly.%20). Will more look into that

Comment: No worries! Ah, I didn't realise you were using Docker Swarm. I haven't worked with it. For simpler/single container configurations where one has good visibility of a container's lifecycle, env vars are OK (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Currently in spring it is very easy.

First lets create 2 secrets:

```
docker secret create magic magic.yml 
docker secret create arctos arctos.yml
```

Above the magic.yml & arctos.yml are configuration files which you would like to keep as docker secrets, for example:

#arctos.yml

```
---
arctos:
  cold: "Very cold!"
```

#magic.yml

```
---
magic:
  value1: "Hello!"
  value2: 20
```

Now lets create Spring Boot simple app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({MagicProperties.class, ArctosProperties.class})
public class SimpleWebServiceApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SimpleWebServiceApplication.class, args);
  }

}

@ConfigurationProperties("arctos")
record ArctosProperties(String cold) {
}

@ConfigurationProperties("magic")
record MagicProperties(String value1, int value2) {
}


@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor // lombok annotation pure constructor can be used
class HelloController {

  private final MagicProperties magicProperties;
  private final ArctosProperties arctosProperties;

  @GetMapping("/magic")
  public MagicProperties magic() {
    return magicProperties;
  }

  @GetMapping("/arctos")
  public ArctosProperties arctos() {
    return arctosProperties;
  }

}
```

#application.yml

```
---
spring:
  application:
    name: hello-secret
  config:
    import: 
      - optional:file:/run/secrets/magic.yml
      - optional:file:/run/secrets/arctos.yml
```

#docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  default:
    driver: overlay
    name: my-network

services:
  hello-secret:
    image: <your_image_here>
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        order: start-first
        monitor: 10s
        delay: 5s
    secrets:
      - source: magic
        target: magic.yml
      - source: arctos
        target: arctos.yml

secrets:
  magic:
    external: true
  arctos:
    external: true
```

Now run:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack
```

And call:

```
http :8080/magic
http :8080/arctos
```

#Post Scriptum

In fact, we can make our app even more flexible. If for example during development/testing we do not want to use secrets we can extend our app a little bit

#application.yml we extend by

```
# Properties
arctos:
  cold: ${ARCTOS_COLD:}

magic:
  value1: ${MAGIC_VALUE1:}
  value2: ${MAGIC_VALUE2:}
```

#docker-compose.yml we extend by

```
environment:
  MAGIC_VALUE1: "env_used"
  MAGIC_VALUE2: 0
  ARCTOS_COLD: "In fact in env area is hot ;]"
```

In such a case when secrets are not linked with our service the environment values are used. (In fact if you provide environment values they have precedence so finally anyway they win).